# Issue in following expressjs statement, picked from Expressjs.com

Tags: node.js, express

The following statement is from http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB . The website states:

> Several callbacks may also be passed, useful for re-using middleware
>   that load resources, perform validations, etc.

```
app.get('/user/:id', user.load, function(){
  // ... 
})
```

The route `'/user/:id'`  does not get executed. It states that `user` is undefined.

Do we need to define `user` as an object?

PS: `user.load` will need to be defined as a callback function, but is useful to provide additional validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can figure out the following use case of the above statement.

```
var user= {};

user.load = function(req, res, next){

    console.log(req.params.id);
    next();

}

app.get('/user/:id', user.load, function(req, res){
    // ...
    res.render('home');
});
```

You are right, it would take the declaration of the object `user` but then it gives you to define additional callback functions, for additional validation/manipulation.